# Gaussian process predictor

Tags: regression, matlab, gaussian-process

I am building GP regressor , my input data is 1-d column vector and so is my target. I have divided my data into training and testing sets. I trained the model to learn the hyper-paramters and then plugged in my input test cases, and I expected to see their corresponding outputs as in the following lines of code :

```
% Split the data
XTrain = BP(1:193,1);
YTrain = BP(1:193,2);
XTest =  BP(194:end,1);
YTest =  BP(194:end,2);
% set meand, cov , lik functions and hyp
meanfunc = {@meanSum, {@meanLinear, @meanConst}};
covfunc = {@covMaterniso, 3};
likfunc = @likGauss;
hyp.mean = [0.5; 1];
hyp.cov = log([1/4; 1]); 
hyp.lik = log(0.1);
%Training and learning parameters 
hyp = minimize(hyp, @gp, -100, @infExact, meanfunc, covfunc, likfunc, XTrain, YTrain);
% Compute predictions 
[m s fm fs] = gp(hyp, @infExact, meanfunc, covfunc, likfunc, XTrain, YTrain, XTest);
% Code ends here
```

Is what I am doing right? and how can I interpret the mean?

Comment: I presume you are using the GPML toolbox? Try plotting XTest vs m.

Answer (score 1):

The "mean" `m` is actually your prediction. The variance `s` can be interpreted as the uncertainty of your prediction.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to plot the data like in the examples in gpml. This is how you can do that:
         z = linspace(-1.9, 1.9, 101)';
         [m s2] = gp(hyp, @infExact, meanfunc, covfunc, likfunc, x, y, z);

```
     f = [m+2*sqrt(s2); flipdim(m-2*sqrt(s2),1)]; 
     fill([z; flipdim(z,1)], f, [7 7 7]/8)
     hold on; plot(z, m); plot(x, y, '+')
```

source: http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/