# Choosing covariance function

Tags: normal-distribution

Is there a systematic approach or a specific methodology by which we can choose covariance functions that best suit a particular data set? Was carl in his GPML evaluating the suitability of the covariance function when he computed the value of nlml?

Comment: To what does that last sentence refer?  In being so mysterious, this sounds like it belongs as a comment to another thread rather than as a question in its own right.

Comment: Ali, that's your third question dealing with [Gaussian processes](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/) in less than 24 hours. Still, we can only get an idea of what you're after from this question, [Gaussian process predictor](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23767/930). It would be better if you could focus on one particular issue at a time or provide more details on your particular design.

Comment: I asked if there is a systematic approach of chossing covariance functions? I wanted to make sure of Carl Rassmussen Tutorial on GPML when he chose the covariance function and he cmputed the negative log marginal liklihood value, was he evaluating his choice (choice of covaraince function)? I am sorry for being vague in my question which might still be thanks

Comment: @Ali Please [register your](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/login) account and don't use answers for comments.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to choose a covariance function is according to prior knowledge of the problem, e.g. is the distribution of data stationary, is it smooth, etc.

In the absence of prior knowledge it is common to choose the covariance function (and hyper-parameters) by optimising some suitable model selection criterion, for instance the negative-log-marginal-likelihood (nlml) or some (leave-one-out) cross-validation performance estimate.  However, this in no panacea, as both  nlml and cross-validation based model selection criteria are evaluated on a finite sample of data and hence have a non-zero variance (if you repeat the analysis on different samples of data you get different values).  This means it is possible to over-fit the model selection criterion, and you end up with a poor model, especially if you make many choices by having either a large number of hyper-parameters or a large number of covariance functions to choose from (or both).  The nlml also has the disadvantage that if the model is misspecified, then the nlml is not a very good indicator of generalisation performance (as it assumes that the model is not misspecified), so it may end up recommending a bad choice of covariance function, so in principal, cross-validation is likely to be more robust in such situations.

I've done some work on this area, and was surprised how susceptible kernel models (and GPs) are to this problem, see

G. C. Cawley and N. L. C. Talbot, Preventing over-fitting in model selection via Bayesian regularisation of the hyper-parameters, Journal of Machine Learning Research, volume 8, pages 841-861, April 2007. ([www](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v8/cawley07a.html))

and

G. C. Cawley and N. L. C. Talbot, Over-fitting in model selection and subsequent selection bias in performance evaluation, Journal of Machine Learning Research, 2010. Research, vol. 11, pp. 2079-2107, July 2010. ([www](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v11/cawley10a.html))

I've been looking into the problem of data-driven choice of covariance function, and I haven't found a method yet that is generally much better than just using the squared exponential covariance all the time.